# Script unlock cannot submit, budget overspent

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli, transaction, script, validator

I'm  trying to unlock some token at a script address, so I create a tx with cardano-cli transaction build ... this passes successfully, then I sign the tx. It is now ready for submit but when I submit I get this error:

`Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (UtxosFailure (ValidationTagMismatch (IsValid True) (FailedUnexpectedly [PlutusFailure "\nThe 3 arg plutus script (PlutusScript ScriptHash \"9f8863d5eb3f855c406ff38f29daa84e41ba0f3f1203bbe54275cf5f\") fails.\nCekError An error has occurred:  User error:\nThe budget was overspent. Final negative state: ({ cpu: -119092 | mem: -400 })`

After this I get a detail of the Tx followed by a big patch of non-readable text. (This same error also appears in the output of the syncing testnet node I'm running)
Anyone knows what's the issue and how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error says your contract is over resource budget.

```
 User error:
   The budget was overspent. Final negative state: ({ cpu: -119092 | mem: -400 })
```